# Visual Studio Code, los iconos no se ven como antes

Tags: vscode

Mis iconos donde se veían que tipo de archivo era, dejaron de estar como estaban, ahora solo me salen iconos iguales.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Reinicistas y se arreglo? borraste todos las extensiones y se arreglo?

Comment: Los iconos se pueden cambiar con extensiones. Busca la que tenías antes o instala otra y selecciona los nuevos iconos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahi instale una extension de iconos, mas exactamente "Material Icon Theme".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para elegir el tema que se usa en los iconos entra al editor y presiona `CTRL + SHIFT + P`, escribes "icono", seleccionas "Preferencias: Tema de icono de archivo"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego eliges el que quieras.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]